# Php Switch gives back the first case only

Tags: php, function, switch-statement

I implemented this function using php switch in order to convert set of binary code into letter/numbers. 
When I callback the function on a variable containing the binary code, it gives back always the first case.
Any idea?

```
<?php

if (!function_exists('baudot')){
function baudot(){
        switch(true) {
        case '111000' : $decid= 'A';    break;
        case '110011' : $decid= 'B';    break;
        case '101110' : $decid= 'C';    break;
        case '110010' : $decid= 'D';    break;
        case '110000' : $decid= 'E';    break;
        case '110110' : $decid= 'F';    break;
        case '101011' : $decid= 'G';    break;
        case '100101' : $decid= 'H';    break;
        case '101100' : $decid= 'I';    break;
        case '111010' : $decid= 'J';    break;
        case '111110' : $decid= 'K';    break;
        case '101001' : $decid= 'L';    break;
        case '100111' : $decid= 'M';    break;
        case '100110' : $decid= 'N';    break;
        case '100011' : $decid= 'O';    break;
        case '101101' : $decid= 'P';    break;
        case '111101' : $decid= 'Q';    break;
        case '101010' : $decid= 'R';    break;
        case '110100' : $decid= 'S';    break;
        case '100001' : $decid= 'T';    break;
        case '111100' : $decid= 'U';    break;
        case '101111' : $decid= 'V';    break;
        case '111001' : $decid= 'W';    break;
        case '110111' : $decid= 'X';    break;
        case '110101' : $decid= 'Y';    break;
        case '110001' : $decid= 'Z';    break;
        case '100100' : $decid= ' ';    break;
        case '011000' : $decid= '-';    break;
        case '010111' : $decid= '/';    break;
        case '001101' : $decid= '0';    break;
        case '011101' : $decid= '1';    break;
        case '011001' : $decid= '2';    break;
        case '010000' : $decid= '3';    break;
        case '001010' : $decid= '4';    break;
        case '000001' : $decid= '5';    break;
        case '010101' : $decid= '6';    break;
        case '011100' : $decid= '7';    break;
        case '001100' : $decid= '8';    break;
        case '000011' : $decid= '9';    break;
        default:        $decid='NIL';
        }   
        return $decid;
}
}

$serid1='000011'; 
$serid2='110100'; 
echo baudot($serid1).'<br/>';  // should give 9
echo baudot($serid2);          // should give S
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wrong with using the switch case. Check updated code.

**You need to pass the id parameter to your function and then use that parameter in switch-case.**

```
<?php

function baudot(string $id){
        switch($id) {
          case '111000' : $decid= 'A';  break;
          case '110011' : $decid= 'B';  break;
          case '101110' : $decid= 'C';  break;
          case '110010' : $decid= 'D';  break;
          case '110000' : $decid= 'E';  break;
          case '110110' : $decid= 'F';  break;
          case '101011' : $decid= 'G';  break;
          default:        $decid='NIL';
        }   

        return $decid;
}


echo baudot('111000'); // Prints A
```

Comment: You actually don't explain *why* the first result is always returned. Without it you don't actually explain what's wrong. You just give them working code.

Comment: I think it's kinda "self-explanatory", from what I said, I think he will be clever enough to understand difference between my code and his code and understand that he needs the parameter inside function and then use it inside switch case. Your answer is just too much information, what is not really needed in this simple case. :)

Comment: But it is not self explanatory. Type juggling is not obvious and is a common pitfall in PHP, hence why we have this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you are comparing each value to the Boolean `true`. The first value is the string `111000`. Since any non-empty string is considered to be `true`, when PHP type juggles (because you are comparing two different data types) your string, which is true equals true.

What it looks like you want to do is compare it to a value, not a Boolean `true`. So you need to use that in your `switch` statement instead. This is accomplished by passing the values as a parameter to your function and then using it in your `switch` statement:

```
function baudot($value){
    switch($value) {
```

Comment: Nice answer John. Very well-explained, IMHO.

Comment: Thanks John for the explanation! It makes sense.